# PDF generate in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I must generate PDF from twif view.
I am trying use this http://www.michaelperrin.fr/2016/02/17/generating-pdf-files-with-symfony/

But, I have a problem.

My config.yml

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
```

My controller:

```
$html = $this->render('order/pdf.html.twig');
$filename = sprintf('test-%s.pdf', date('Y-m-d'));

$response = new Response();

$response->setContent($this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml($html, '/home/xxx/domains/xxx.hekko.pl/public_html/web/pdf/test.pdf'));
$response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```

And I have an error

```
[2016-07-10 14:54:02] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "The exit status code '127' says something went wrong: stderr: "sh: wkhtmltopdf: command not found " stdout: "" command: wkhtmltopdf --lowquality '/tmp/knp_snappy5782456ab8c340.15653998.html' '/home/xxx/domains/xxx.hekko.pl/public_html/web/pdf/test.pdf'."
```

What is wrong?

I have shared hosting, maybe I must have VPS?

Comment: Have you check the binary path ? It is the same than in your config.yml ? (Maybe it is not the 64bits version)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think Ugo is right, I think I saw this same message when installing on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Use `uname -a` to check your architecture and verify you have the correct version of "wkhtmltopdf" installed.